# create a 4 column gird in html

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This might be an easy one to do, but I am struggling since morning. I am trying to create a 4 column grid like the below, where the values for all the 4 columns are generated by running a for loop.
[image]

Here is the html I created

```
  <template for:each={provinces} for:item="province">
    <div class="province-section" key={province.key}>
      <div>{province.province}</div>
      <div>{province.stats}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

CSS

```
 .province-section {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
 }
```

Please advise!

---

EDIT: Added output of the above code:

I am using Salesforce templating system. The issue I have is that the column count could go upto a maximum of 4, but sometimes it can be lower than that and the values for the columns are not preset as well. Below I am adding the output of my current code. In the below output the values Alberta and its stats below should be on the same level and British Columbia, which is what I have been trying to do since morning.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, this was amazing, so many answers in half an hour. I have edited my code with the output of my current code. Please check it out and please advise. Thanks all again.!

Answer (score 4):

1. When you want to create a grid - the `display: grid` should be in the container of the elements (not on each element).
2. If you want to have 4 columns, you probably want to use `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);`
3. Note that your example uses some templating system, which is not a standard part of html. When you post here you should also mention which templating system you are using, or another option - add the output html (after the processing of your templating system).

Here is a working example:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="province-section" key={province.key}>
        <div>Province</div>
        <div>Stats</div>
    </div>
    <div class="province-section" key={province.key}>
        <div>Province</div>
        <div>Stats</div>
    </div>
    <div class="province-section" key={province.key}>
        <div>Province</div>
        <div>Stats</div>
    </div>
    <div class="province-section" key={province.key}>
        <div>Province</div>
        <div>Stats</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a four-column grid that can have text in the columns

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* this will clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: That's how we used to do it in the stone age.